# Why this code is giving error?

Tags: java, recursion

```
package geek;

public class Gfg {

    // constructor
    Gfg() {
        System.out.println("Geeksforgeeks");
    }

    Gfg a = new Gfg(); 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gfg b; 
        b = new Gfg();
    }
}
```

This program when run is giving 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Why is it giving this error?

Comment: what do you mean i cannot understand

Comment: ... because each time you create a `Gfg` instance another `Gfg` instance is created, which creates another one, which creates ...

Comment: so I am creating Gfg insatnce only once in main then the instace in the class will also be called once only. Then why StackOverflow error?

Comment: I repeat: **Each time you create an instance another one is created.** The first one creates the second one. The second one creates the third one. The third one creates the fourth one. The fourth one ... Got it?

Comment: When you write `Gfg a = new Gfg();` compiler is moving `a = new Gfg();` to each constructor of Gfg, which means when you call `new Gfg()` internally another `a = new Gfg();` will be called, ant inside that another `a = new Gfg();` and inside that another `a = new Gfg();` and so on, so on.

Comment: For your second question, you can't place expressions like that at the class level. You could have `Gfg a = new Gfg();` there in the first example because that's creating an instance member, which is allowed there.

Comment: It should be noted that the OP completely changed the question since it was closed.

Comment: Don't change your question into another one. If you have new question (even related to this one) post it as separate one.

Comment: More info: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is causing a StackOverflow because you're creating an instance of the class within the class itself. This leads to infinite recursion that tries to create infinite nested instances of Gfg.

Remove `Gfg a = new Gfg();` as it serves no purpose.

Comment: why is it leading to recursive calls even if I am creating object only once

Comment: @Ankit Think about it. When you create an instance, it will call `Gfg a = new Gfg();`, which creates another  instance, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be run, which creates another instance, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be called again, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be run, which creates another instance, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be called again, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be run, which creates another instance, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be called again, which causes `Gfg a = new Gfg();` to be run, which creates another instance, which...

Comment: my doubt is that when Gfg b=new Gfg() will execute then constructor will be called and then the execution will come back to main then how will Gfg a=new Gfg1() will be reached. If it had been inside a constructor then I can understand that it will lead to satckOverflow. How is it leading in this case

Comment: @Ankit Because `Gfg a = new Gfg();` creates an instance field for the class, so it's run before control goes back to main. Are you just starting out learning classes?

Comment: @Ankit It basically is in the constructor. `Gfg a = new Gfg();` outside of the constructor is basically the same as `Gfg a; Gfg() { a = new Gfg (); System.out.println("Geeksforgeeks"); }`. Do some more studying on instance fields/members. It'll all make sense then.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the following line, which causes infinite recursion:

```
Gfg a = new Gfg();
```

This is executed whenever a `Gfg` is instantiated. Since this line will instantiate a new instance, the line will be called again.